# Wordpress recommending to downgrade instead of upgrade?

Tags: updates

First time seeing this, is this normal behaviour? Thanks guys

[image]

Comment: No. If you look at https://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/ you won't see 4.2.1 at all, so it's not getting it from there. Something somewhere in your install or network is intercepting the update API check, or filtering the output afterwards to point you at 4.2.1.

Comment: Is this anything suspicious or something? should I be alarm?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, no, but there could be lots of reasons and it's not necessarily malicious. Look for _site_transient_update_core in your database: is this long-lived with data for version 4.2.1? Maybe try deleting that (and _site_transient_timeout_update_core) - the 4.2.1 should then go away for ~12 hours. If it doesn't you've got a filter insisting on 4.2.1 somewhere in your code you can track down.

Comment: If it comes back as 4.2.1 then you've either got a filter on the update_core transient or option, or something on your network is intercepting the API call. Can you run shell commands from your server? Try requesting that URL using curl and see what the output looks like. Maybe your host or an old developer put in a hack to force an upgrade once that's still in place.